# How to return the value closest to zero

Tags: sql-server

I got a table with a numeric-column that contains both positive and negative numbers. How do I find the record with det number closest to zero?

This query

```
SELECT MIN(ABS(dNumber))
FROM myTable
```

returns det smallest absolute value. However I want the signed value returned.

So if myTable contains 2 records; one with dNumber = 2000, second with dNumber = -1000, I want the query to return -1000, and not 1000.

EDIT:
Forgot to mention this has to be in an aggregate funtion as its part of a query with GROUP BY

```
SELECT Key1, Key2, 
   SUM(CASE WHEN /*condition1*/ THEN dNumber ELSE NULL END) AS 'Value1',
   SUM(CASE WHEN /*condition2*/ THEN dNumber ELSE NULL END) AS 'Value2',
   MIN(ABS(dNumber)...) AS 'ClosestToZeroAndSigned'
FROM myTable
/*joins*/
WHERE /*conditions*/
GROUP BY Key1, Key2
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I. stand-alone query

```
SELECT top 1 dNumber
FROM myTable
order by ABS(dNumber)
```

II. a part of larger query with group by

```
;with cte as
(
  SELECT Key1, Key2,
   SUM(CASE WHEN /*condition1*/ THEN dNumber ELSE NULL END) AS 'Value1',
   SUM(CASE WHEN /*condition2*/ THEN dNumber ELSE NULL END) AS 'Value2',
   -- max negative value
   max(case when dNumber <= 0 then dNumber else null end) as Negative,
   -- min positive value
   min(case when dNumber  > 0 then dNumber else null end) as Positive
  FROM myTable
  /*joins*/
  WHERE /*conditions*/
  GROUP BY Key1, Key2
)
select 
    Key1, Key2, Value1, Value2
    Negative, Positive,
    case when (abs(Negative) < Positive or Positive is null) then Negative else Positive end as 'ClosestToZeroAndSigned' 
from cte
```